# can i get changed text of JTextField. this text is changed every one minute

Tags: swing

How can we get text filed value, this value actually is changes after every 5 second or 1 minute. pls let me.
Regard
Satish Dhiman

Comment: `JTextField#getText` gives you the text, and the textfield fires events when the text is changed

Comment: TextFieldID.getText(); method will give you the content in a particular text field. Is that what you want to happen?

Comment: [whathaveyoutried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

`setText()` is used to set the text in JtextFeild
if u want it to work every 5 secs 
then use `swing Timer` that would invoke after every 5 sec and this way you can change the text ever 5 secounds

Comment: `java.util.Timer` is a bad idea in combination with Swing components. Better to use the `javax.swing.Timer`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a method every time the text has changed, append an `ActionListener` to the textField like this. The method `actionPerformed()` is called every time the textfield receives an action, maybe you need an other XXXListener for your task.

```
textField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
          System.out.println("the text has changed");     
     }
};
```